# why does javac in ant build script error with incompatible types

Tags: java, spring, ant

I have an ant build script that errors out with the following message.

```
javac incompatible types by ant build

ProductDao.java:41: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: java.util.List<com.sample.dto.Product>
            listProductsIds = jdbc.execute("{ call find_Product_id(?,?,?,?,?) }",
                                        ^
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

But If I test it in my eclipse IDE everything works fine.

I'm using Spring JdbcTemplate and here is how I defined my call.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Product> getProducts(final String parent, final String tagDesc,
            final int pageSize, final int pageNo, 
            final String userId, final int maxrowcount) {

        List<Product> listProductIds = new ArrayList<Product>();

        listProductIds = jdbc.execute("{ call find_Product_id(?,?,?,?,?) }",
                new CallableStatementCallback() {

                    public Object doInCallableStatement(
                            CallableStatement callableStatement)
                            throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                        callableStatement.setString(1, parent);
                        callableStatement.setString(2, tagDesc);
                        callableStatement.setInt(3, pageSize);
                        callableStatement.setInt(4, pageNo);
                        callableStatement.setString(5, userId);
                        callableStatement.execute();
```

Comment: By the way, independently of your error message there, your `= new ArrayList<Product>()` is superfluous, as you are throwing away this list in the next line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Eclipse's compiler is being overly forgiving here, and compiling something it shouldn't do, whereas `javac` (used by Ant) is being stricter. The `jdbc.execute` method, as you're using it here, returns `Object`, which you can't assign to `List`.

You've suppressed warnings on your code, which isn't helping either, so you're effectively ignoring the messages that are telling you what's wrong.

You need to use the generics to help you, so that the correct return type is used:

```
List<Product> listProductIds = jdbc.execute(
    "{ call find_Product_id(?,?,?,?,?) }",
    new CallableStatementCallback<List<Product>>() {
        public List<Product> doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement callableStatement) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
            ....
        }
    }
);
```

Note that the generic type signature of the `CallableStatementCallback` matches the return type of `doInCallableStatement`, and the type of the `listProductIds` variable. You don't need, and shouldn't have, warning suppressions in this sort of code.

Comment: I agree with your analysis of what's happened (and I've encountered this myself), but sometimes casting is the answer. For example, I did this in an automated tests which used Jersey ClientResponse - I cast the response into a List<supertype> instead of the actual class. Eclipse and the runtime were tolerant of this without an explicit cast, but it was necessary for javac.